# inverse SVD square matrix with rectangular orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal, svd

I'm trying to prove the inverse matrix of $X=U\Sigma^{}V^T$ is $X^{-1}=V\Sigma^{-1}U^T$.

X is invertible and dxd square matrix, U and V are orthogonal matrices, which are dxk, and $\Sigma$ is kxk matrix.

Since the orthogonal matrices are rectangular, $U^TU=V^TV=I\neq VV^T$

When we inverse the matrix X, then

$X^{-1}=(U\Sigma V^{-1})^{-1} = V\Sigma^{-1}U^{-1}$

Since $U^TU=I$, we can say when $U^T$ is multiplied to the left side of U, $U^T=U^{-1}$.

However, in the above $X^{-1}$case, can we say $U^{-1}=U^T$?

Also, can we say $U^{-1}=(U^T)^{-1}$ since $U^TU=I$?

If not, how do we prove $X^{-1}=V\Sigma^{-1}U^T$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to prove is quite wrong.  If a matrix is not square, then it is not invertible.  No exceptions.  Even a square a matrix is only invertible if all of the columns (equivalently, rows) are linearly independent.

The only way to bypass this is to come up with what are known as **pseudoinverses**.  One of the most famous of these is the **Moore-Penrose inverse**, which for a matrix $A$ is typically denoted as $A^+$ and is of the form:

$$
A^+ \;\; =\;\; A^T\left (AA^T\right )^{-1}.
$$

Note that this is only possible if $AA^T$ is invertible (this matrix is square) but $A^+$ only serves as a right inverse since $AA^+ = I$ but $A^+A \neq I$ in general.

**Edit**

In the case that $A$ is square and invertible, then we find that each piece of the SVD is invertible as well.  Hence if $A = U\Sigma V^T$ then the inverse is given by

$$
A^{-1} \;\; =\;\; \left (U\Sigma V^T\right )^{-1} \;\; =\;\; \left (V^T\right )^{-1}\Sigma^{-1}U^{-1} \;\; =\;\; V\Sigma^{-1}U^T, 
$$

which follows directly from the properties of the inverse.

Comment: Hi, I modified my question. What would be the case if the matrix is a square and invertible?

Comment: @user19283043 See edits.

Comment: How can we say $(V^T)^{-1}=V$?

Comment: @user19283043 This is a defining property of orthogonal matrices.  Orthogonal matrices are defined as those $V$ such that $V^TV = VV^T = I$.  This implies that $V^T = V^{-1}$.

Comment: However in my case, V is a rectangular matrix (d x k), so $V^TV=I$ and $VV^T \neq I$.

Comment: But can we say $V=(V^T)^{-1}$ from $V^TV=I$ condition?

Comment: @user19283043 You said you modified your question so that the matrix is square and invertible, in which case each of $U, \Sigma,$ and $V$ would be square and of the same size.  If $V$ is not square then only one of the directions $V^TV = I$ or $VV^T = I$ (depending on dimensionality), but not both.

Comment: Yes, so A would be the square and invertible matrix and U, V are d x k orthonormal matrices, and $\Sigma$ would be k x k diagonal matrix. So only one direction would be true ($V^TV=I$). Then my confusion is whether I can say ($V=(V^T)^{-1}$) based on this condition ($V^TV=I$), otherwise, I'm not sure how to prove the A inverse.

Comment: @user19283043 If a matrix $V$ is not square then it's impossible to write $V^{-1}$.  It's simply incorrect to write this.  Note that if you're determined to take a square invertible $d\times d$ matrix and to artificially include a diagonal matrix $\Sigma$ in the SVD of dimension $k\times k$ then we would necessarily have $k > d$ since there will be $d$ nonzero singular values.  This means that not even $\Sigma$ would be invertible since it would have rows and columns that were all zero.  To me it seems that you're trying to accomplish something which is impossible.